# Page header is not repeating in rdlc report when two tablix is having two dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, dataset, rdlc

I'm having a one strange scenario. Before going into it, I want to say that I'm very beginner to this rdlc report. Hence I'm struggling to resolve it.

**What I want is ?**

I want to show the page header in all the pages.

**What I have is ?**

I'm having one header part which is having few textboxes and the body part which is having two tablix. Here, the two tablix consists of two difference datasets. The first tablix is grouped under Group1.

**What the issue I face is ?**

The first tablix consists of 50 records, that occupies three pages. In all the three pages, the header part is visible. When the second tablix is coming into the fourth page, all the header part turned into **# error**. Really struggling a lot to solve this.

**What I tried is ?**

1. Opened Advanced Mode in the Groupings pane.
2. Clicked static and changed the Keepwithgroup = after and Requestonnewpage = true.

**Note :** I did this for the two tablix but nothing works. Also I'm not sure that this will give the way.

3. Also I checked in report xml file also.
4. Checked Repeat row on each page and Repeat column on each page.

Hope you understand my problem. Kindly guide me where I'm making mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say "all the header part turned into # error" - can you check what is the error (check in Output window)? I suspect you are referring to elements that are no longer present on the page, but maybe there is something else involved. Also, can you clarify if this is second's tablix header that gives you errors or the first one's? Do you expect header for first tablix to show even though report continues and shows second tablix? ...it's a little confusing the way you described it.

Comment: @InitK. Thanks for your reply. Yes you are right. I'm referring the header from first tablix to second one. Isn't possible ?. If not, can you give some suggestion to proceed ?

Comment: Instead of using page headers you could place everything inside tables. By creating a single column tablix and replacing the textbox from the cell by a rectangle you can probably get the wanted result. The column header then becomes the page header and the row represents the page's body. You could then simply create a second table to get the other header.